# Using jQuery AJAX to pass JSON Object to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I have a JSON object like this (assigned to `var card;`):

```
{
    card_no: "1", 
    card_name: "wwwgdefonru",  
    img_id: 1, 
    img_thumb: "albums/070915_E239/thumbs/001_wwwgdefonru.jpg", 
    img_hires: "albums/070915_E239/thumbs_hires/001_wwwgdefonru.jpg"
}
```

I want to pass this using AJAX to a php support file.

Here's my AJAX call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: ajax_file,
    type: 'JSON',
    data:  card,
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        console.log('SUCCESSO');
        jQuery('#debug').html(html);    
    },
    complete:function(){
        console.log('COMPLETE');
    }
});
```

In my PHP file (just for debugging purposes) I output the passed data like so:

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

The AJAX call completes successfully. But the output is blank:

```
Array
(
)
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

**SOLUTION**

I am working on a project with an old version of jQuery (don't ask...). From looking at the docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) I could see that setting the method using `method: 'POST'` wasn't working because it isn't supported by the version of JQ I am using. Switching it to `type: 'POST'` and getting rid of `type: 'JSON'` fixed it.

I wouldn't have spotted this had I not looked at the network tab and seen the request Method was `GET` even though I have defined it as `POST`.

Comment: Replace `method:` with `type:`

Comment: @mccannf - no difference. I get the same result

Comment: @Rasclatt tried that with mccannfs suggestion and without. Same result.

Comment: `type` is an alias for `method`. Use one or the other and don't give it the value `"JSON"`.

Comment: **Don't** use `contentType: 'application/json',`. You aren't sending JSON.

Comment: Look at the Net tab in your developer tools. Look for the Ajax request. Does it have the data in it you expect? Is it going to the right URL?

Comment: @Quentin - good suggestion, I should've thought of that. This helped me fix the issue. I'll update my answer with the solution.

Answer (score -1):

The method of writing [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method is in this way is so easy for you

```
$.post("your_php_file_url.php",
    {
        card_no: "1", 
        card_name: "wwwgdefonru",  
        img_id: 1, 
        img_thumb: "albums/070915_E239/thumbs/001_wwwgdefonru.jpg", 
        img_hires: "albums/070915_E239/thumbs_hires/001_wwwgdefonru.jpg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Response Message" + data + "\nResponse Status: " + status);
    });
```

In your PHP site you read the values using

```
<?php
     echo $_POST['card_no'];
?>
```

like this you could get other values and do your works!

Comment: While starting again from scratch *might* solve the problem, its hard to be sure unless you can identify the actual problem with the existing code.