# How to pass correctly a php json_encode value to a table that is using DataTables plugin?

Tags: php, json, datatables

I'm working on a project that using a payment gateway and i would like to display values from payment API in JSON format to a table that use [Datatable JS plugin](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html). Firstly, i found some similar questions related with my doubt, but unfortunately i'm having some dificulties to find a correct way to solve this.

1. [Using jQuery AJAX to pass JSON Object to PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440271/using-jquery-ajax-to-pass-json-object-to-php-file)
2. [How to parse nested JSON object in ajax using DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299760/how-to-parse-nested-json-object-in-ajax-using-datatables)
3. [How to pass JSON object to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235317/how-to-pass-json-object-to-php)
4. [How to pass json object using PHP in Wepay API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832234/how-to-pass-json-object-using-php-in-wepay-api)
5. [Display JSON object using DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893407/display-json-object-using-datatables)

I'm using a php Curl script that call an URL API and get results in JSON format:

**all_payments.php**

```php
<?php 

$token = "TOKEN_PROD";

$ch = curl_init('URL_API');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
   ));

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo $data;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

And below are the API results in JSON format when Curl script above are executed:

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "corporation_id": null,
            "operation_type": "regular_payment",
            "fee_details": [],
            "notification_url": null,
            "date_approved": null,
            "money_release_schema": null,
            "payer": {
                "first_name": "Test",
                "last_name": "Test",
                "email": "test_user_80534729@test.com",
                "identification": {
                    "number": "34579430",
                    "type": "DNI"
                },
                "phone": {
                    "area_code": "01",
                    "number": "1111-1111",
                    "extension": ""
                },
                "type": "registered",
                "entity_type": null,
                "id": "660948681"
            },
            "transaction_details": {
                "total_paid_amount": 10,
                "acquirer_reference": null,
                "installment_amount": 0,
                "financial_institution": "",
                "net_received_amount": 0,
                "overpaid_amount": 0,               
                "payable_deferral_period": null,
                "payment_method_reference_id": "1848987916",
                "verification_code": "1343987916"
            },
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "call_for_authorize_id": null,
            "installments": 1,
            "pos_id": null,
            "external_reference": null,
            "date_of_expiration": "2020-10-20T22:59:59.000-04:00",
            "charges_details": [],
            "id": 1453987916,
            "payment_type_id": "ticket",
            "barcode": {
                "content": "23791841402309310003380250122998791600633330"
            },
            "order": {
                "id": "1820096336",
                "type": "mercadopago"
            },
            "counter_currency": null,
            "brand_id": null,
            "status_detail": "pending_waiting_payment",
            "differential_pricing_id": null,
            "additional_info": {
                "ip_address": "123.456.678.890",
                "nsu_processadora": null,
                "available_balance": null
            },
            "live_mode": false,
            "marketplace_owner": null,
            "card": {},
            "integrator_id": null,
            "status": "pending",
            "transaction_amount_refunded": 0,
            "transaction_amount": 10,
            "description": "Short",
            "money_release_date": null,
            "merchant_number": null,
            "refunds": [],
            "authorization_code": null,
            "captured": true,
            "collector_id": 58546234946,
            "merchant_account_id": null,
            "taxes_amount": 0,
            "date_last_updated": "2020-10-17T11:30:31.000-04:00",
            "coupon_amount": 0,
            "store_id": null,
            "date_created": "2020-10-17T11:30:31.000-04:00",
            "acquirer_reconciliation": [],
            "sponsor_id": null,
            "shipping_amount": 0,
            "issuer_id": null,
            "payment_method_id": "ticket",
            "binary_mode": false,
            "platform_id": null,
            "deduction_schema": null,
            "processing_mode": "aggregator",
            "currency_id": "USA",
            "shipping_cost": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on JSON results above, i'm trying to pass some JSON objects to inside a table that use Datatables Plugin. Below are the html and javascript codes that display a table with Datatable plugin:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    
   <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>date created</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>total_paid_amount</th>
            <th>status</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
    
</table>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable({

          "ajax": {
          "url": "all_payments.php",
          "dataSrc": "results"
            },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "date_created" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "total_paid_amount" },
            { "data": "status" }
        ]
    });
    });
    
    </script>
```

When the page with Datatable reload, i get an error on browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at jquery.dataTables.min.js:65
    at h (jquery.dataTables.min.js:52)
    at Object.success (jquery.dataTables.min.js:52)
    at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

In this case, how could i improve the Curl php script (**all_payments.php**) to pass JSON correctly to table that is using Datatables plugin? I tryed to replace:

```php
echo $data;
```

to

```php
$decode = json_decode($data,true);

    foreach ( $decode["results"] as $value){
        echo $value["id"];
        echo $value["date_created"];
        echo $value["email"];
        echo $value["total_paid_amount"];
        echo $value["status"];
    }
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I edited **all_payments.php** script as below:

```php
<?php

//setup your token payment or others
$token = "PROD_TOKEN";

//setup the request, you can also use CURLOPT_URL
$ch = curl_init('API_URL');

// Returns the data/output as a string instead of raw data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Set your auth headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
   ));

// get stringified data/output. See CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// get info about the request
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$new_array = array(); // this array should be empty

$decode = json_decode($data);

// access property of object in array
echo '{"data":';
foreach($decode->results as $item) {
  $new_array[] = array(
    'id' => $item->{'id'},'date_created' => $item->{'date_created'}, 'email' => $item -> payer ->{'email'}, 'total_paid_amount' => $item -> transaction_details ->{'total_paid_amount'}
    );  
}

echo json_encode($new_array);

echo '}';
// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

On **foreach** the script get object values and then output results passing json values to Datatables, as code below:

```html
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('#example').DataTable( {

        "ajax": "all_payments.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "date_created" },
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "total_paid_amount",
            
                render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$ ' )
                
            },
        ],
        
    "columnDefs":[
        {"targets":1, render:function(data){
      return moment(data).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    }},
    
            {"targets": 3,
        "className": 'dt-body-right'}
    
    ]

    });
  
    });
    
    
    </script>
```

That's it. If anyone would like to improve this code, feel free.